# Non-transparent confidence intervals in seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, eps

**Context:**
The journal I want to submit my paper to only accepts `.tiff` (doesn't work with LaTeX), `.jpg` (not suitable for graphs), and `.eps` (which doesn't work with alpha transparency, unless I rasterize the image, which leads to huge file sizes). Many of my plots use seaborn's `regplot`, which plots transparent confidence intervals. Is it possible to plot non-transparent CIs without completely re-doing all of my graphs manually (e.g. as dashed lines or a solid color in the background)?

**Example:**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

sns.set_style("ticks")
np.random.seed(0)
n = 50

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,6))

x = np.random.randn(n)
y1 = np.random.randn(n)
y2 = np.random.randn(n)

sns.regplot(x, y1, ax=ax)
sns.regplot(x, y2, ax=ax)

plt.show()
```

[image: Example of a regplot with transparent overlapping confidence intervals]

What would be the easiest / best way to save this as an .eps file without losing information from the overlapping confidence intervals?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you need transparency to show the two confidence intervals overlapping. One would need to rasterize the image.

I don't actually see the problem of using jpg if the journal accepts it. You may control the quality of the image using

```
plt.savefig(__file__+".jpg", quality=95)
```

Using eps is also possible, here,  instead of rasterizing everything, you may rasterize only the confidence interval `fill_between`-curves. The advantange is that the axes, labels and points are still vecor graphics and won't look pixelated on different zoom levels.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import PolyCollection as p
import seaborn as sns

sns.set_style("ticks")
np.random.seed(0)
n = 50

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,6))

x = np.random.randn(n)
y1 = np.random.randn(n)
y2 = np.random.randn(n)

sns.regplot(x, y1, ax=ax)
sns.regplot(x, y2, ax=ax)

plt.savefig(__file__+".jpg", quality=95)
for c in ax.findobj(p):
    c.set_zorder(-1)
    c.set_rasterized(True)
#everything on zorder -1 or lower will be rasterized
ax.set_rasterization_zorder(0)

plt.savefig(__file__+".eps")
plt.savefig(__file__+".png")
plt.show()
```

The final eps file looks like this:
[image]

While the filesize is of course a bit larger, I'm not sure if this is a real problem.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know you could only rasterize parts of the image. That's pretty neat. Thanks! The journal is pretty strict about file sizes, which is why I didn't want to use mostly uncompressed JPGs. For the initial submission, I used a workaround of replacing the `fill_between` part in the seaborn source code with dashed lines, but your solution looks much more elegant.

Comment: PS why are you comparing the string repr of the type instead of using `isinstance`? Also I think matplotlib axes have a function that returns all artists of a given type, but I forget what it's called.

Comment: @mwaskom The function you mean is called `ax.findobj`. I was simply too lazy and copied the str repr from the output. But I changed it now. Concerning jpg, it's of course not ideal, but there is very little difference between a png and a jpg if the jpg quality is high enough. You will always need to stick to the journal's requirements, whether they make any sense or not.